# Enabling .dev functionality on github enterprise

Tags: github, editor, github-enterprise

On normal GitHub there is a possibility to go to a repo in browser and either press `.` or change the domain to `.dev` and it will open code editor in the browser. May I know, how can I enable this `.dev` functionality on the GitHub enterprise.

Looking forward to the suggestion and advice.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this GHEC or GHES?

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about GitHub Codespaces - each codespace you create is hosted by GitHub in a Docker container, running on a virtual machine.

If you use GHES, the feature is unavailable as GitHub hosts it.
If You have GHEC - it can be possible that Your Organization or Enterprise Owner disabled it not to generate extra costs.